# How to hide/show specific lines with a checkbox on a line chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I made a multiple line chart visualization with d3.js. But with so many lines (each line is a column on my dataset), it's obviously unreadable. So I want a checkbox where the user can choose which line he wants to display. My problem is, in all the tutorials I see, I need to manually write the name of each column I want to display in the checkbox...is there a way to take automatically all my variables in the checkbox ?

As an example, I would like a result like this one : https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_select.html

For the moment I only have a script which displays all my variables on the graph, and I don't know what I need to add.

I leave you my code it its current state:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test pollen avec code D3 Graph Gallery</title>
  <style>
    body {
font: 12px sans-serif;
    }
.axis path,
axis line {
fill: none;
stroke: #000;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
x.axis path {
display: none;
}
.line {
fill: none;
stroke: steelblue; stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 style="margin: 2em;">Concentration pollinique au Luxembourg, 1992-2018</h1>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    const margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 100},
width = 1200 - margin. left - margin. right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin. bottom;
// formater date
const parseDate = d3. time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
const x = d3.time.scale()
  .range ([0, width]);
const y = d3.scale. linear()
  .range ( [height, 0]);
const color = d3. scale. category10();
// axes x et y avec leur orientation
const xAxis = d3. svg.axis ()
  .scale (x)
  .orient ("bottom");
const yAxis = d3. svg.axis ()
  .scale (y)
  .orient ("left");

const line = d3.svg.line()
.interpolate ("basis")
.x(function(d) { return x(d. date); }) 
.y(function(d) { return y(d.concentration); });

let svg = d3.select ("body") .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append ("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin. left + "," + margin.top + ")");


d3.csv ("pollen_tri.csv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain (d3.keys (data[0]).filter(function (key) { return key !== "date"; })); 

  data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate (d.date);
  });

  var plants = color.domain().map (function (name) {
  return {
    name: name,
  values: data.map(function (d) {
  return {date: d.date, concentration: +d [name]};
    })
  };
});

x.domain (d3.extent (data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([
  d3.min(plants, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {return v.concentration;}); }),
  d3.max(plants, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.concentration;});})
]);


svg.append("g")
  .attr("class" , "x axis") 
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call (xAxis);

  
svg.append ("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis") 
    .call (yAxis) 
  .append ("text")
  . attr("transform", "rotate (-90)") 
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", " .71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end") 
  .text ("Concentration (pollens/m3)");

var plant = svg.selectAll(".plant")
    .data(plants)
  .enter() 
  .append ("g")
  .attr("class", "plant");  


plant.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });  


});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's also an image of my current graph:
[image]

Finally, here's a sample of my csv file:

| date | Ambrosia | Artemisia | Asteraceae | Alnus | Betula | Ericaceae | Carpinus | Castanea | Quercus | Chenopodium | Cupressaceae | Acer | Fraxinus | Gramineae | Fagus | Juncaceae | Aesculus | Larix | Corylus | Juglans | Umbellifereae | Ulmus | Urtica | Rumex | Populus | Pinaceae | Plantago | Platanus | Salix | Cyperaceae | Filipendula | Sambucus | Tilia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1992-01-01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1992-01-02 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1992-01-03 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1992-01-04 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1992-01-05 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1992-01-06 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1992-01-07 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1992-01-08 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1992-01-09 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: If you include a sample showing the format of the CSV file, we will be able to run your code ourselves and give a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to automatically create checkboxes which will show/hide the lines.

I used plain Javascript, but you could do the same thing using d3.

This example creates checkboxes ([`<input type="checkbox">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox)). To get a dropdown menu instead, use [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) and [`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option).

There are three steps:

1. Create a Javascript object which will map a plant name to an SVG `<path>`. In other words, it will let us look up an SVG `<path>` from a plant name.
2. Populate the map.
3. Create checkboxes and add event listeners.

The code I changed:

```js
const mapPlantNameToSvgPath = {};

plant.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function (d) { return line(d.values); })
    .style("stroke", function (d) { return color(d.name); })
    //
    // https://d3js.org/d3-selection/control-flow#selection_each
    .each(function (d) {
        const svgPath = this;
        const plantName = d.name;
        mapPlantNameToSvgPath[plantName] = svgPath;
    })


color.domain().forEach(function (plantName) {

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label
    const label = document.createElement("label");

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox
    const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkbox.setAttribute("checked", "true");

    checkbox.addEventListener("change", function () {
        const svgPath = mapPlantNameToSvgPath[plantName];

        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/visibility
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            svgPath.setAttribute("visibility", "visible");
        } else {
            svgPath.setAttribute("visibility", "hidden");
        }


    });

    label.append(checkbox);
    label.append(document.createTextNode(plantName));

    document.body.append(document.createElement("br"));    
    document.body.append(label);
});
```

Screenshot (with fake data in the csv file):

[image: line plot with checkboxes to show or hide lines]